# problems with test methods

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

I'm having problems with my test methods.  For example, I stripped everything else down from this code

```
@isTest
global class RestSalesData_TEST {

    testmethod static  void testRestSalesData() {
        Test.startTest();

        test.startTest();

    }   

}
```

And I get the error 
"Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Test.startTest()"

Same with other methods such as Test.setMock.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your list of classes. Odds are, you have a class named Test, which is shadowing the system Test class. You can rename/remove the class, or you can use System.Test instead:

```
System.Test.startTest();
```

Comment: How the heck is that not a reserved keyword...

Comment: @AdrianLarson For more fun and games, create a class named Schema...

Comment: Oh man, that breaks all the workarounds for naming collisions. That's just evil.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It also disables all Schema methods, like Schema.getGlobalDescribe, because System.Schema doesn't exist :pout: